# TIdHttp freezes when the internet gets slower

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, indy

How to avoid freezing the idHTTP when the internet become slower or no connectivity. My application get freeze and I could not even close the form.

This is how I setup my code

```
procedure TDownloader.IdHTTPWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCount: Int64);
var
  lwElapsedMS: LongWord;
  iBytesTransferred: Int64;
  iBytesPerSec: Int64;
  iRemaining: Integer;
begin
  if AWorkMode <> wmRead then Exit;

  lwElapsedMS := GetTickDiff(FLastTicks, Ticks);
  if lwElapsedMS = 0 then lwElapsedMS := 1; // avoid EDivByZero error

  if FTotalBytes > 0 then
    FPercentDone := Round(AWorkCount / FTotalBytes * 100.0)
  else
    FPercentDone := 0;

  iBytesTransferred := AWorkCount - FLastWorkCount;

  iBytesPerSec := Round(iBytesTransferred * 1000 / lwElapsedMS);

  if Assigned(OnDownloadProgress) then
  begin
    if FContinueDownload <> 0 then //previous file downloaded
    begin
      iRemaining := 100 - FContinueDownload;
      iRemaining := Round(FPercentDone * iRemaining / 100);
      OnDownloadProgress(Self, FContinueDownload + iRemaining, AWorkCount, FTotalBytes, iBytesPerSec);
    end else
      OnDownloadProgress(Self, FPercentDone, AWorkCount, FTotalBytes, iBytesPerSec);
  end;

  FLastWorkCount := AWorkCount;
  FLastTicks := Ticks;

  if FCancel then
  begin
    Abort;
    TidHttp(ASender).Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TDownloader.IdHTTPWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCountMax: Int64);
begin
  if AWorkMode <> wmRead then Exit;

  FPercentDone := 0;
  FTotalBytes := AWorkCountMax;
  FLastWorkCount := 0;
  FLastTicks := Ticks;
end;

procedure TDownloader.IdHTTPWorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
begin
  if AWorkMode <> wmRead then Exit;
  if Assigned(OnDownloadComplete) and (FPercentDone >= 100) then
    OnDownloadComplete(Self)
  else if Assigned(OnDownloadCancel) then
    OnDownloadCancel(Self);
end;

function TDownloader.EXDownload(AURL, ADestFile: String;
  AAutoDisconnect: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  fsBuffer: TFileStream;
  idHttp: TIdHttp;
begin
  if FileExists(ADestFile) then
    fsBuffer := TFileStream.Create(ADestFile, fmOpenReadWrite)
  else
    fsBuffer := TFileStream.Create(ADestFile, fmCreate);

  fsBuffer.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
  try
    idHttp := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
    idHttp.OnWorkBegin := idHttpWorkBegin;
    idHttp.OnWork := idHttpWork;
    idHttp.OnWorkEnd := idHttpWorkEnd;
    idHttp.Request.CacheControl := 'no-store';
    try
      ...
      idHttp.Get(AURL, fsBuffer);
      ...
    finally
      idHttp.Free;
    end;
  finally
    fsBuffer.Free;
  end;
end;
```

......

```
procedure TDownloader.Execute;
begin
  Inherited;
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    if FUrl <> '' then
    begin
      EXDownload(FUrl, FFilename, True);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

...
on the main form progress

```
procedure TfrmDownloadList.DownloadProgress(Sender: TObject; aPercent:Integer;
    aProgress, aProgressMax, aBytesPerSec: Int64);
var
  yts: PYoutubeSearchInfo;
begin
  if Assigned(FCurrentDownload) then
  begin
    yts := vstList.GetNodeData(FCurrentDownload);
    yts.Tag := aPercent;
    ProgressBar.Position := aPercent;
    vstList.InvalidateNode(FCurrentDownload);
    StatusBar.Panels.Items[1].Text := 'Download: ' + FormatByteSize(aProgress) + '/' +
      FormatByteSize(aProgressMax);
    StatusBar.Panels.Items[2].Text := 'Speed: ' + FormatByteSize(aBytesPerSec) + 'ps';
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;
```

I don't have problem when the internet is good only when it drops due to poor signal.
this is my app [lookslike](http://prntscr.com/2kxcux)

Comment: The answer to questions that contain the word "freezes" usually is: use threads. If ´TDownloader´ is already a thread (not obvious here), then the code you posted is not the reason why your app freezes. Maybe  some wait call in the main thread?

Comment: TDownloader is a tread, if i have i good signal, work is fine. the progress bar works well, i can drag my window flawlessly even even downloading ?>800mb. but when the signal drops my app it begins not responding.

Comment: How do you update your progress bar? Please include all relevant code in the question.

Comment: Show code for idHttpWorkBegin, idHttpWork and idHttpWorkEnd;.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that TDownloader.OnDownloadProgress is assigned to the TfrmDownloadList.DownloadProgress method, then your problem is that you are calling VCL code (your update of the progress bar) from a secondary thread (ie. not from the Main thread). This is not supported.

You'll need to wrap the call with a Synchronize statement from within your thread. Synchronize calls a parameterless method on the main thread. So you need to store the variables that are needed and then call Synchronize on a method in your TDownloader class that then calls on to TfrmDownloadList.DownloadProgress

You cannot call TfrmDownloadList.DownloadProgress directly or indirectly from within code that runs on another thread than the main thread, as it updates VCL objects, and the VCL is not thread-safe.

The same goes for your DownloadComplete event, if it updates any VCL objects...

Comment: i get your point. but TDownloader is a class base on Tthread there is so no direct calling to the main form. what i did is FDownloader := TDownloader.Create; and assigned Events on it. by the way, TfrmDownloadList is my Main form.

Comment: It does not matter whether the main form is used directly or via events. The point is that you set properties of VCL controls from a secondary thread - which is not allowed. You need to call that event in the context of the main thread - use `PostMessage` or `Synchronize`.

Comment: @XBasic3000: Your OnWork event handlers are called in the context of the worker thread that is using `TIdHTTP`. They then call your own status event handlers in the context of that same worker thread. Your status handlers are then updating the UI in the context of that same worker thread, NOT in the context of the main UI thread.

Comment: @jpfollenius, yes i think your right. i try to change my implementation. thanx for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

How about you using TIdAntiFreeze ?

> TIdAntiFreeze implements a GUI-integration class that ensures
>   processor time is allocated for the Application main thread.
>
> Indy works on the blocking sockets model. Calls made to methods in the
>   Indy components do not return until they are complete. If calls are
>   made in the main thread, this will cause the Application User
>   Interface to "freeze" during Indy calls. TIdAntiFreeze counteracts
>   this effect.
>
> TIdAntiFreeze allows Indy to process Application messages so that
>   Windows messages continue to be executed while Indy blocking socket
>   calls are in effect.
>
> Only one TIdAntiFreeze can be active in an application.

Comment: OP is already using a thread, so there is no need for `TIdAntiFreeze`